# How do I target a specific panel of JQuery Panel Switcher from a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery Content Panel Switcher https://code.google.com/p/jquery-content-panel-switcher/ and I use the 'show' class in on a panel to show the default panel when a page loads, but what if I want to target a different panel?

Could I pass a variable in the URL what would switch the show class to a different panel?

Comment: you could probably use a hashtag then use a script to change the panel view

Comment: Hey, just checking, did my answer get you what you needed? Any further comments or clarification that would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you're using there doesn't really have a clearly documented API, but theoretically it's possible. I'm going to show an example of how this would be done with a plugin that works the same way but is a little more solid and well-documented -- [the tabs widget from jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/), and using hashed urls like the first comment suggests.

```
// simple url parser
// (via https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561)
var url = document.createElement('a');
url.href = window.location.href;

// get the url hash as an integer
var activeTab = parseInt(url.hash) || 1;

// initialize tabs on the '.selector' element
$( ".selector" ).tabs('active', activeTab);
```

This way, you would be able to hash your url with the number of the tab you wanted open, and the tabs plugin would initialize with that tab open (or the first one by default). For example, if you hit `http://example.com#3`, the third tab would be open. If you wanted to make these words, it would be easy to add a little switch statement that mapped the numbers and strings.

An example and docs for jquery ui tabs [can be found here](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/), and the docs for the 'active' method I used in this example [can be found here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active).